# Control page scroll animation with mousewheel and mouseup,mousedow

Tags: jquery

can anybody help me understand how achieved this effect: https://www.apple.com/sg/mac-pro/

I mean the ease when you scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Parallax

you can find an exemple of javascript's plugin [here](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)

Answer (score 0):

With CSS alone, you could get this
http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/